# Replace NULL in a dataframe

Tags: r

I've the following dataframe:

```
  freq.a freq.b              
1 NULL   0.055               
2 0.030  0.055              
3 0.060  0.161                    
4 0.303  0.111                   
5 0.393  0.111                   
6 0.121  0.388                   
7 0.090  0.111
```

And I would like to replace the `NULL` with an actual 0. However executing `df.m[is.null(df.m)] <- 0` doesn't change anything in the dataframe.

MWE as follows(sorry for the length):

```
library(plyr)
df.a <- c(5, 4, 5, 7, 3, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3, 6, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 4)
df.b <- c(1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 7, 7, 4, 3, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5)
df.a.count <- count(df.a)
df.b.count <- count(df.b)

#normalize the data
df.a.count$freq <- lapply(df.a.count$freq, function(X) X/length(df.a))
df.b.count$freq <- lapply(df.b.count$freq, function(X) X/length(df.b))
df.m <- merge(df.a.count, df.b.count, by ='x', all=TRUE)[2:3]
names(df.m) <- c('freq.a', 'freq.b')

#replace the NULL's with 0
df.m[is.null(df.m)] <- 0
```

Comment: If you look at the `str(df.m)` each column is a `list`.  `lapply` returns a `list` and that is the reason.

Comment: Try `apply(df.m,2,function(y) sapply(y,function(x) ifelse(is.null(x),0,x)))`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You shouldn't use `lapply`. Use `sapply` instead. This will produce `NA`'s instead of `NULL`'s. You can then do:

```
df.m[is.na(df.m)] <- 0
```

**Explanation:**

`lapply` returns a list instead of a vector. In lists you can have NULL values. `sapply` returns the same values in form of a vector, but with `NA`s instead of `NULL`s.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the use of `lapply` which returns a `list` and it can be easily found be looking at the structure of the dataset i.e. `str(df.m)`.

We can also do this using `base R` alone.  Get all the `unique` elements from both the `vector`s ('lvls'), convert both the datasets to `factor` by specifying the `levels` as 'lvls', get the frequency count (`table`) and the proportion (`prop.table`), `cbind` the output and `round` if necessary.

```
lvls <- sort(union(unique(df.a), unique(df.b)))
round(cbind(prop.table(table(factor(df.a, levels = lvls))), 
                  prop.table(table(factor(df.b, levels = lvls)))), 3)
#  [,1]  [,2]
#1 0.000 0.056
#2 0.030 0.056
#3 0.061 0.167
#4 0.303 0.111
#5 0.394 0.111
#6 0.121 0.389
#7 0.091 0.111
```

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe column should be character then replace NULL in zero (0) and change this dataframe in numeric mode so that we can use other function as aggregate etc.

```
df[, 4:17][df[, 4:17] == "NULL"] <- 0
```